# Assign list of IP's to a list of switches in Python

Tags: python

How would I be able to assign a list of switches to a range of IP's?

EX:

```
list = [switch1.com, switch2.com, switch3.com, ...] 
ip = [10.15.15.1, 10.15.15.2, all the way to 10.15.15.254]
```

I want to be able to assign the first switch in the "switch list" to the first IP in the "IP list".  If there are more IP's than switches, I don't want it to assign multiple IPs to the switches.  Only want one IP per switch.

Comment: Do you want one to be the key and the other the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want the following?

```
>>> sws= ['switch1','switch2','switch3']
>>> ips = ['10.15.15.1','10.15.15.2','10.15.15.3','10.15.15.4']
>>> print zip(sws,ips)
[('switch1', '10.15.15.1'), ('switch2', '10.15.15.2'),('switch3', '10.15.15.3')]
```

Comment: What makes this better than `zip`?

Comment: No, it's no better than zip in this case. Just updated, thanks.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I was wanting the script to still run even if the list of IP's had more values than the list of switches.

Answer (score 1):

```
if len(ip) == len(list):
    return zip(ip, list) # Returns [("10.15.15.1", "switch1.com"), ...]
```

Or if you want one to be the key and the other the value:

```
if len(ip) == len(list):
    ret = {}
    for i, j in zip(ip, list):
        ret[i] = j
    return ret
```

Comment: you can remove the `return` statement from `if condition` :)

Comment: There's no `return` in the `if` condition, and frankly, I've never seen anyone return in an `if` condition`.

Comment: @avasal But none in the if condition.

Comment: if the OP uses your code,, he will get a syntax error `'return' outside function`

Comment: @avasal That statement is probably true.

Comment: You will get the syntax error, 'return' outside function.  I put it in a function and it ran without the error. Thank you for the help on this.